# Modify a Cookie's value

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to set a secure session for a login interface and I'm checking if some hashed value saved on the `$_COOKIE` and in `$_SESSION` matches in both arrays. I need to change the value of the cookie via javascript to simulate an attack and check if my secure session works (if that is even possible, of course). Deleting the cookie wont work because I have a different validation for when the cookies doesnt exist.

Is it possible to modify a cookie's value via javascript and if so, how to?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to modify a cookie's value via javascript and if so, how to?

*Yes.* Provided it lives under the same domain and path, you [can ready, modify, create, or destroy cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704991/can-i-modify-or-add-cookies-from-javascript) either by JavaScript (`document.cookie`) or PHP (`$_COOKIE` and `set_cookie()`).

As noted, you could also manipulate cookies via the developer tools of most modern browsers.

Comment: *sidenote:* requires to be in same domain path if cookie domain path is specified

Comment: @Shivan Raptor, added. Thanks. For more on how domains work, check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work

Answer (score 0):

Since cookies are actually stored within the browser, it is definitely possible :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: it is preferred to give examples to OP.

Comment: True, however at the bottom of that reference is a sufficiently thorough example. ;)