# set-cookies in response headers is 'half' working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cookies

I have a node.js API server(e.g. http://host:9002) that needs to set cookies in client, while I have two version of clients, a jQuery one and an AngularJS one. Both client runs at e.g. http://host:8001 behind a nginx as static files.

The question is the exactly same API server returns the exactly same response with `set-cookie` head, but in jQuery client, the cookie is simply not be set while in AngularJS client, everything is fine. This is what I mean 'half' working and made me really frustrated.

I've tried chrome and safari, the same result.

In AngularJS client, I use `$resource` to send request and In jQuery is '$.ajax'.

The set-cookie in response head is the following one(inspected by chrome):

```
connect.sid=<some session id here>; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

What i have tried is to move the jQuery client also serves at http://host:9002, and this makes the set-cookie head works. To me, it looks like that i'm violating Same Origin Policy. But why angularJS client is working though?

=================
UPDATE:

for example, the `account/login` API:

In AngularJS:

```
m.factory('accountlogin', ($resource)->
  $resource(UrlServer+'/account/login',{},{
    login: {method:'PUT', params:{}, isArray:false}
  })
)
```

and using as:

```
accountlogin.login({
    username: u,
    password: p,
  }, function(r) {
    //some callback here;
  });
```

While in jQuery:

```
sys{
    req:function(url, type, data,callback){
        var path = sys.SERVER_BASE;
        $.ajax({
            type : type,
            url : path + url,
            dataType : "json",
            data:data,
            success : function(data){
                if(callback)callback(data)
            },
            error:function(data){
                if(callback)callback(data)
                console.log('fail');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

using as:

```
var _data = {
    username:$('.loginName').find('input').val(),
    password:$('.loginPassword').find('input').val(),
}

sys.req("account/login", 'PUT', _data, function(data){
    if(data.status == 'success'){
        // some success callback
    }else if(data.status == 'failed'){
        // some failed callback
    }else sys.output('Login failed');
})
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you're expecting to happen, and what actually happens? Don't forget that your cookie is HttpOnly so is not accessible in JavaScript at all.

Comment: this is not right you can read create and delete a cookie using javascript using `Document.cookie` , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704991/can-i-modify-or-add-cookies-from-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in Response header, I add `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` in $.ajax, and the cookies finally could be set.

Source code as following:

```
req:function(url, type, data,callback){
    var path = sys.SERVER_BASE;
    $.ajax({
        type : type,
        url : path + url,
        dataType : "json",
        data:data,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        success : function(data){
            if(callback)callback(data)
        },
        error:function(data){
            if(callback)callback(data)
            console.log('fail');
        }
    });
},
```